# Is it possible to make Gnome Terminal show the name of the file I am editting in vim as the tab title?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, vim, gnome-terminal

I often have several files open in vim, each in a different tab. I have to remember which tab has which file open. Is there a way to show this in the tab titles?

Comment: `vim` supports tabs (both in the GUI and on the command line), so you do not *need* to use tabs from `gnome-terminal`. See `:help tabpage`.

Comment: @honk: Thanks, that's pretty neat! I think I'm going to stick with `gnome-terminal` tabs, so that I can use `alt + [tab number]` to switch between them. Or is there a way to do this in `vim`, too?

Comment: CTRL-PgUp/gt and CTRL-PgDown/gT for switching to next/previous tab, and also e.g. 2gt to go to tab 2. Not sure if the CTRL part is default or depends on the terminal setup.

Comment: @honk: `gnome-terminal` steals `CTRL-PgUp/PgDown` when multiple terminal tabs are open (it works when `vim` is the only one). `2gt` works, but neither option is as convenient for `ant + [tab number]` anyway. Thanks for the tip, though, I'll remember it if I'm ever stuck using a terminal without tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_set_screen_title):

Add this to your .vimrc:

```
let &titlestring = hostname() . "[vim(" . expand("%:t") . ")]"
if &term == "screen"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
  set title
endif
```

Comment: `:set title` is enough for `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: For anyone curious: To make the title *just* the filename, change the first line to `let &titlestring = expand("%:t")`.

Comment: `:set title` is enough for `terminator` too - I added this to the .vimrc

Answer (score 1):

More simple way for gnome-terminal, write below in your vimrc :

```
set title
autocmd BufRead * let &titlestring = expand("%:p")
```

show only filepath in title